# Load word vectors from a text file - GENSIM PYTHON

Tags: python, gensim, word2vec

Hello i have a txt file in this form, in the first column is the word and in the second its vector.

```
word 0.256 0.2659 0.326595
word1 0.528 0.6589 0.62326 ...
```

i am trying to load this as keyedvectors because I want to compute after the cosine similarity between the words and find the most similar words but I always get an error.

Comment: Could you please phrase a question you would like answered?

Comment: To a sympathetic reader, the clear statement "I am trying to [X]" is the same as the question "How can I [X]".

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing the actual format includes line breaks, like:

```
word 0.256 0.2659 0.326595
word1 0.528 0.6589 0.62326
```

That's more-or-less the format common for GLoVe-trained vectors, & very similar to the text format used by Google's original `word2vec.c` code - which adds a 1st line with a count of vectors & their dimensionality.

(If your vectors came from one of those tools, or a public place, & there are more hints as to their format from the filename or origin, that would have been helpful to note in your question.)

If I'm guessing your true format correctly, then Gensim's `KeyedVectors` class can load the GLoVe format via the `.load_word2vec_format()` method, with the `no_header=True` optional parameter:

```py
vecs = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format(filename, binary=False, no_header=True)
```

See the docs for more options:

https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/keyedvectors.html#gensim.models.keyedvectors.KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format

Comment: That's what i am looking for, thank you very much! To compute the most similar words between my dataset and one random word by cosine similarity i run this command right? 
   ```vecs.most_similar('man',topn=20)  ```

Comment: Did you try that command? Did it return reasonable results?